# Select data column wise from csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I have csv file like

```
a, b, c, d
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

And i want output like below using php

```
a 1 5 9
b 2 6 10
c 3 7 11
d 4 8 12
```

Comment: and so far you tried what code?

Comment: `str_replace(',', '', $string)` perhaps? Come on, this is trivial at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
<?php
$row=str_getcsv(string);

$field=array('a','b','c','d');
$n=0;
while($n<count($field)) { 
echo $field[$n]
foreach($row as $item){
    echo $item[$n];
    echo ' ';
}
echo '\n';
$nbfield++
}
```